# Disable Date in DatePicker [Extjs]

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs3

i want to disable from the 2nd of month to the last day of month.

i.e enable only the first day of month.
also first day of present month should be disable.
i tried

```
format: 'd/m/Y',
disabledDates: ['02/..', '31/..']
```

but it disable only 2nd and 31st of every month.

Although i search more

use

```
disabledDates : ['^01']
```

it helps me to disable the 1st of every month ... however i need the reverse.

Please help :: new to extjs

Answer (score 3):

not pretty, but code snippet is below.

**Please note:**

- this only deals with the first point of "i want to disable from the 2nd of month to the last day of month"
- does not disable the "first day of present month", as I am not sure how that can be accomplished.

```js
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        disabledDates: ['../02/..',
                        '../03/..',
                        '../04/..',
                        '../05/..',
                        '../06/..',
                        '../07/..',
                        '../08/..',
                        '../09/..',
                        '../10/..',
                        '../11/..',
                        '../12/..',
                        '../13/..',
                        '../14/..',
                        '../15/..',
                        '../16/..',
                        '../17/..',
                        '../18/..',
                        '../19/..',
                        '../20/..',
                        '../21/..',
                        '../22/..',
                        '../23/..',
                        '../24/..',
                        '../25/..',
                        '../26/..',
                        '../27/..',
                        '../28/..',
                        '../29/..',
                        '../30/..',
                        '../31/..'],
        maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }]
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to bind disabledDates in your View and using setDisabledDates on your Controller Exemple :

**your item**

```
{ 
 xtype: 'datefield', 
 reference: 'date', 
 altFormats: 'd/m/Y', 
 bind:{ 
   disabledDates :'{dateDisabled}' 
 } 
}
```

**your controller**

```
dateDisabled: function () {
 // your stuff
 return // array with dates to desactivate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`'02/..'` means: "Disable all dates that contain 02/ followed by any two characters." Are you sure that 08/02/2015 is not disabled by this? My guess is, the whole february is disabled.

While you could  create a regexp to say "all days except the first", I would not know how and would use this monster:

```
disabledDates: ['^02', '^03', '^04', '^05', '^06', '^07', '^08', '^09', '^1', '^2', '^3', '01/03/2015']
```

But, for the sake of usability, I would recommend to use different UX elements, since you disable >90% of the dates. Two comboboxes, one for the month and one for the year, would be more suitable, I guess.

Comment: "Two comboboxes, one for the month and one for the year, would be more suitable, I guess."

yeah it will be more suitable ... but i need for all year ... not for 10-15 year.